# Как сделать такую табличку ios

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

[image: табличка]

Как сделать такую табличку на ios, первая колонка должна растягиваться если ее значения не помещаются на экран. Может есть библиотека для этого?

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько способов:

1) UICollectionView с кастомным UICollectionViewLayout, например, статья, с которой можно начать https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html или https://www.raywenderlich.com/527-custom-uicollectionviewlayout-tutorial-with-parallax

2) готовые библиотеки (могут покрыть не все кейсы) : https://github.com/stuffrabbit/SwiftSpreadsheet, https://github.com/KyoheiG3/GridView